# Calendar Box Value

Tags: visual-studio, calendar, messagebox

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.

I'm trying to work it so that if various fields aren't completed on a page, a message box will pop up saying "Please select, etc."  I've done the text boxes and drop-down menus, but I'm struggling with the selected date.

```
    ElseIf Calendar1.SelectedDate = "0" Then
        Message_Box("Please enter Invoice number, Panels, Pallet/Packing List, Pallet and Date.")
        Calendar1.Focus()
```

Now I know that the value for the selected date won't be "0", but I can't for the life of me work out what it should be.  All I want is for it to come up with the message box if no date is selected, or if an old date is entered.

I am a complete noob at this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out with some further research....

```
ElseIf Calendar1.SelectedDate = "01/01/0001" Then
    Message_Box("Please enter Invoice number, Panels, Pallet/Packing List, Pallet and Date.")
    Calendar1.Focus()
```

The default date being 01/01/0001.